# "She talked about how..." Grammar Rule

Tags: grammar, rules

I'm trying to find the grammar rule or name that explains these types of sentences:

1. The movie was about how we all need to love each other.
2. She talked about how there is a great fear of technology.
3. He thought about how magma slowly cools beneath the Earth's surface.

So, the pattern is [verb + about + how + clause]. What's the rule/explanation?

Comment: It's an idiomatic usage, where ***how*** could actually be replaced by ***[explaining] the fact that*** without changing the meaning. One could contrive a context where it would correspond to the more "literal" sense of ***the way in which*** in #3, but it would be difficult to do this for the first two.

Comment: _How..._ is one type of embedded question (or free relative -- there's a difference but it rarely matters) clause. They all start with _Wh-_ words like _how_ and _why_. _How_ questions manner or means, so the embedded wh-question is very vague about precisely what it saying -- everything has manner or means, after all -- but after _talk about, think about,_ etc. the sense is simply that this is the subject of (and perhaps the conclusion reached by) the thought, movie, talk, story, or whatever.